# Xamarin Forms - Navigation Push - Split Screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm convinced I've seen a setting somewhere in Xamarin forms which changes the behaviour of a navigation page.  But I can't seem to find it again.

I believe the behaviour splits the screen in two so when you push a new view to the stack, the current one moves left and the new one takes the right position.

Can anyone please either tell me I'm wrong, I've made it up or point me in the right direction?

Comment: `ContentPage` doesn't behave that way. You would've see `MasterDetailPage` with `MasterBehavior` set to `Split`

Comment: the user can use gestures to enable split screens on an iPad, but there is no API to control this programatically